# Invalid operation: Failed to compile udf

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, fuzzywuzzy

I have imported the fuzzywuzzy library on Redshift from S3. I am trying to create the below function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fuzzy_test (string_a TEXT,string_b TEXT) RETURNS FLOAT IMMUTABLE
AS
$$
FROM fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
RETURN fuzz.ratio (string_a,string_b)
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

But this is throwing an error:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Failed to compile udf
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Failed to compile udf
  code:      10000
  context:     File "/rds/bin/padb.1.0.22169/data/udf/231/978476007/e3afd7ea37e0384bcaf415f60955b5eb6911e3ae/0.py", line 2
    FROM fuzzywuzzy import fuzz fz = fuzz()
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  query:     0
  location:  cg_addins.cpp:257
  process:   padbmaster [pid=4211]
  -----------------------------------------------; [SQL State=XX000, DB Errorcode=500310]
1 statement failed.
```

Please explain me what causing the error.

Answer (score 3):

It worked when FROM and RETURN keywords are in lower case.